# i am getting error when deploying machine learning model in aci

Tags: python, azure, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

**I am getting following error when trying to deploy machine learning model and when i deployed last time (1 month ago) with same score.py file it was deployed successfully, can anyone tell me why its giving error now**

**Error message as below**

```
service.get_logs()

Received bad response from Model Management Service:
Response Code: 404
Headers: {'Date': 'Thu, 29 Jul 2021 12:34:55 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'x-ms- 
client-request-id': '70679512-c060-4340-adb7-b48ce00449f5', 'x-ms-client-session-id': 
'1def55d9-4542-4b5b-b499-81aaa966e48a', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0, 2018-03-01-preview, 
2018-11-19', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X- 
Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'x-request-time': '0.961', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

**My deployment code is below**
aci_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration()

service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                   name='try',
                   models=[model_x],
                   inference_config=inference_config,
                   deployment_config=aci_config,overwrite=True)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared your error message so I can not make sure the root cause. But I have seen same error happening When a region is under heavy load, you may experience a failure when deploying instances.

To mitigate such a deployment failure, try deploying instances with lower resource settings, or try your deployment at a later time or in a different region with available resources.

Trying to allocate less resources, e.g.

> aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1,
> memory_gb=8,
> tags={"data": "text",  "method" : "NB"},
> description='Predict something')

You may have a try.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability